# Variable from data is undefined in methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have two variables in `data`: `date_current` and`days`. And I have `days_get`method which returns all days in current month. I want to define `days` variable as `days: this.days_get()`  but I get error which tells me that `date_current is undefined`.

But if I move definition of `days` into `beforeMount` hook all works fine.

Can I define days in `data`?

Full component code:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Calendar",

  data(){
    return {
      date_current: new Date(),
      days: this.days_get()
    }
  },


  methods: {
    days_get(){
      const date_iteration = new Date(this.date_current.getFullYear(), this.date_current.getMonth())
      let days = []

      while(date_iteration.getMonth() === this.date_current.getMonth()){
        days.push(new Date(date_iteration.getFullYear(), date_iteration.getMonth(), date_iteration.getDate()))

        date_iteration.setDate(date_iteration.getDate() + 1)
      }

      return days
    }
  }

}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: this.date_current is undefined"
```

Comment: You can access the Vue instance inside data() using this keyword. That's why it is giving the error. Try using computed properties.

Comment: @زوہیبخان You can, but it's incomplete, only props are available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well its exactly like you said: when you call days_get within data() then date_current is not yet defined (this happens after data). beforeMounted comes after data so there it would work because then you defined date_current. But even better would be to use a computed property:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Calendar",

  data(){
    return {
      date_current: new Date()
    }
  },


  computed: {
    days(){
      const date_iteration = new Date(this.date_current.getFullYear(), this.date_current.getMonth())
      let days = []

      while(date_iteration.getMonth() === this.date_current.getMonth()){
        days.push(new Date(date_iteration.getFullYear(), date_iteration.getMonth(), date_iteration.getDate()))

        date_iteration.setDate(date_iteration.getDate() + 1)
      }

      return days
    }
  }

}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```